# Windows 7 clock gets stuck and internet disconnects

Tags: windows-7, clock, cmos

Few hours after every synchronization of the Windows clock with an internet server, it gets stuck. Along with it (I don't know the exact timing), the internet disconnects. Reconnecting (with or without clock resynchronization), the connection would last for a few hours and disconnects again.

I have already replaced the CMOS battery but it didn't fixed the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use `Internet Time` ? check the corresponding tab in the date and time settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable internet time sync altogether. This prevents the time from getting messed up when you have a poor internet connection. (I prefer to not have my computer sync with online servers for this same reason.)

Here is how you disable internet time sync:
[image]