# Wireless continually drops on WIndows 7, as well as clock freezing

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My issue is similar to [Windows 7 clock gets stuck and internet disconnects](https://superuser.com/questions/616317/windows-7-clock-gets-stuck-and-internet-disconnects), but it seems that question was lost in time.

My laptop will lose internet connection (it's using wireless) despite my hard-wired pc, and other wireless devices seeing no interruptions.  Each time this happens, the clock also freezes and stays frozen, with or without internet time sync turned on.  Simply running the troubleshooter will restore the connection, but it happens again and has been for over a month now.

I'm running windows 7, and can provide any other needed specs.  My question is what can I do to narrow down where the issue is coming from.  Also possibly relevant, the laptop is somewhat old and has heat dispersing issues, so it's possible something is fried or getting there, I'm just uncertain how to discover the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well Michael, You've kinda answered your own question.

- When a system clock stops or loses time:
  It could be the battery on the Motherboard is failing.
- When a Computer overheats:
  The CPU shuts down to protect itself.

Don't panic.

1. Get a grounding wrist strap. They're cheap and that's what they teach at university. Static kills computers. Keep yourself well grounded.
2. Find a tutorial on line specific to your unit and carefully take it apart.
3. Replace the on-board battery (it's the keep-alive, coin type).
4. While you're there, clean up the fans and heat sinks and shoo away all the dust bunnies. This is why old units overheat.

Caveats: Place all you parts and screws in a recognizable pattern on a flat surface, resembling the assembled unit. It's a Beeatch to lose control of the re-assembly process.
No VACUUMS. You don't have the right kind. Me either. Air cans only. Don't spin the fans. It's fun, but when a DC fan spins backwards, it generates electricity, it wears them out, and serves no useful purpose. Hold the blades and use a soft brush.Vacuum the work area **after reassembly**.

I just rebuilt my 2006 e1705. It's now reporting 5.8 on the index. New screen, T7600 CPU, 4 Gb RAM, GeForce 9950 GTX, 1TB HDD, 3 USB 3.0 ports, triple booting XP(still updating), Win 7 Ultimate, Fedora 20.
***Reduce, reuse, recycle***.

Comment: The computer's clock stopping wouldn't be from the BIOS battery being dead, it would still continue to count. The time, however, would be reset when the computer reboots... also, when PCs overheat, they just shut off completely, they don't turn off certain services

Comment: By GeForce 9950 GTX, do you mean GTX 950? Because Nvidia never launched any GPU with that model number as far as I know.